# Does UIView transparency affects a performance of an app?

Tags: ios, uiview, transparency

I'm creating an app where there're up to 40 UIViews where every view stores a drawing of a stick on it which is available in several positions, rotated to 30 degree angle, 45 degree angle etc). Background of a View is transparent. These views can intersect with each other, so I need the UIViews to be transparent in order a user could see both drawings from overlapped and overlapping view. I wonder if this affects a performance of an application seriously? (all this transparency of all 40 UIViews). And how I can track how much memory or CPU my app currently uses.

Comment: Transparency always has some level of performance impact. Whether it actually matters or not can only be determined through testing and analysis. Try it. If there's no problem then you are done. If you have a problem then figure out where and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend watching [WWDC 2012 Session 238](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) - iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations, which covers these questions.

As a broad answer:

1. The iPhone will probably handle your 40-view requirement fine—but its impossible to know for sure without trying it out, and without more context (are they being animated? Are they scrolling?)
2. More views creates more performance problems, because all of the views need to be packaged up and shipped off to be rendered (by `backboardd` I think).
3. Transparency will hurt application performance. I believe the core reason is that transparent views need to be drawn in an off-screen buffer rather than be painted over existing content (something like that).
4. Use Instruments for Profiling

   - Profile your GPU usage using the Open GL ES Driver (look at 'Device Utilization')
   - Measure CPU usage using Time Profiler
   - Measure FPS and check for common performance problems using the CoreAnimation instrument

I wouldn't bother thinking about this until you actually see performance issues. If you do, I can't recommend that WWDC session enough—it covers things like what strategy you should take to optimize performance (e.g. moving work to the GPU as long as it can handle more; the basics of profiling, etc.) as well as tips and tricks based on the implementation details of iOS.

Comment: ty for quick response and the list of instruments for profiling. I'll finish my app first before making an optimisation then.